# Is there any R code that can help me find a word from a list of words against a column in dataframe that contains words to match

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that contain text:

```
Df1: "hello world", "dark world thor", "hello there"
Df2: "world hello", "thor dark world", "there hello"
```

I want to check whether values in `df1` are in `df2` if so add a column that shows `TRUE/FALSE`

thanks :)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: expected output is:

hello world = TRUE
darkworldthor = TRUE
hello there = TRUe

Comment: Greetings! Generally speaking, it is always better to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with on SO. Here you have just a coded block with what it contains, which isn't really the same thing. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to use this function by watching this video:
https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, what you want will be this:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- data.frame(
matrix(
  c(
    "hello world", 
    "dark world thor", 
    "hello there"
  ),
  nrow = 3,
  ncol = 1,
  byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(NULL,
                  c("word1"))
),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df1_match <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(matched =
           str_detect(word1, "^(?=.*\\bhello\\b)(?=.*\\bworld\\b).*$|^(?=.*\\bthor\\b)(?=.*\\bdark\\b)(?=.*\\bworld\\b).*$|^(?=.*\\bhello\\b)(?=.*\\bthere\\b).*$")
         )
```

Ideally, you would make that gigantic regular expression in `str_detect` into an object. For example, here's your data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  matrix(
    c(
      "world hello", 
      "thor dark world", 
      "there hello"
    ),
    nrow = 3,
    ncol = 1,
    byrow = TRUE,
    dimnames = list(NULL,
                    c("word2"))
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Turning that second dataframe into an object to be used in the regular expression is tough. I thought something like the following would work, but it clearly doesn't. Not sure what I'm missing here ...

```
df2_mod <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(word2 = strsplit(x = word2, split = " ") %>% 
           map(~paste0("(?=.*\\b", .x, "\\b)")) %>% 
           paste0("^", ., ".*$")
  ) %>% 
  .$word2 %>% 
  paste0(., collapse = "|")

df1_match_alt <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(matched =
           str_detect(word1, df2_mod)
  )
```